# Error code 1005 - Can't create table

Tags: mysql

Having trouble adding a foreign key to my table.

```
CREATE TABLE event (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    issued DATETIME NOT NULL,
    user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    attending BIGINT(255) NOT NULL,
    attendees VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    organisers VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    place BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    started DATETIME NOT NULL,
    stopped DATETIME NOT NULL,
    content LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    broadcasting TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (place)
            REFERENCES place (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user)
            REFERENCES user (username)
)
```

The foreign key for place is executing fine but once I try adding user as a foreign key I keep getting the same error:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'iservices.event' (errno: 150)

Can anyone help?

Picture of user table:
[User table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNwOL.png)

Picture of place table:
[Place table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI9Li.png)

Is there anyway of expanding the errors in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: why is user a varchar?

Comment: It refers to a username.

Comment: Show both reference tables

Answer (score 0):

a foreign key has to be [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp), so make username unique (which is probably not the best idea) or choose something different like the user id.

My advice: add a primary auto-increment key to the user table and use it as the foreign-key.

Comment: As you can see from the picture I added, it is unique. It is a PK in the user table.

Comment: The user table was already part of the application before I started working on it and cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

1. Referenced column must be unique. It's OK in your case.
2. Columns in child and parent table must be of the same type. In your case they are different.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something here. Where can you see that the types are different?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Another question. Are there any data in these tables?

Comment: There is, yes. 

Username is being used as a FK in multiple other tables as well which is why this one has me stumped.

Comment: Adding FK checks values in parent/child tables. All values from child table must exist in parent table, otherwise MySQL raises an error.

Comment: Try to run this command `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` just after the your query. It will show some information about the foreign key error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure `user` and `place` tables exist and have corresponding columns set as `primary key`? The below snipper works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE user(username VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE place(id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE event (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    issued DATETIME NOT NULL,
    user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    attending BIGINT(255) NOT NULL,
    attendees VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    organisers VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    place BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    started DATETIME NOT NULL,
    stopped DATETIME NOT NULL,
    content LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    broadcasting TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (place)
            REFERENCES place (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user)
            REFERENCES user (username)
)
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/497832/1/0)**.

Comment: They are both created. I have pictures added to my question that confirms this.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar error.
This can occur when you are trying to add a non-primary key from the primary table as the foreign key in the secondary table.

To avoid this, the foreign key in the secondary table has to be the primary key in the primary table.